# How to get tomorrow date in mql5?

Tags: mql4, mql5

I want to draw a horizontal trendline that extends from today to tomorrow, And I have trouble getting time tomorrow.

for example today is `2021.12.17 00:00:00`

```
Comment( iTime(_Symbol, PERIOD_D1, 0) + (PERIOD_D1*60) );

// Today: 2021.12.17 00:00:00    
// MQL4:  2021.12.18 00:00:00 ... it's ok.
// MQL5:  2021.12.28 09:28:00 ... it's not ok! why?
```

**MQL4**: As you can see in the code above, in mql4, through the `iTime` function and adding a period, the date of tomorrow can be obtained, it's return `2021.12.18 00:00:00` .

**MQL5**: But this code shows date `2021.12.28 09:28:00` in mql5.

In other words, `PERIOD_D1` is equal to `1440` in mql4 but in mql5 is equal to `16408`, **Why?**

```
Comment(PERIOD_D1);
// MQL4: 1440
// MQL5: 16408 why?!!!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike MQL4, PERIOD_D1 does not relate to the amount of minutes in the period in MQL5. The simple workaround is to add (1440*60) to iTime().

Alternatively, use [PeriodSeconds()](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/common/periodseconds) as below

```
iTime(_Symbol, PERIOD_D1, 0) + PeriodSeconds(PERIOD_D1)
```